# Horovod instalation in Google Collab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, horovod

i've tried many different versions with:

```
!pip install horovod==0.26.1
```

and also:

```
!HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 pip install horovod[tensorflow] --no-cache-dir horovod
```

Always gets the same error:

```
  Collecting horovod==0.15.0
  Downloading horovod-0.15.0.tar.gz (113 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 113.2/113.2 kB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from horovod==0.15.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.4.0->horovod==0.15.0) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: horovod
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for horovod (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for horovod
  Running setup.py clean for horovod
Failed to build horovod
ERROR: Could not build wheels for horovod, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

what I am doing wrong, is pip broken?

Comment: Please show the complete output that you get. Not just the last lines

Comment: completed the post but there is not much information. Even in a clean colab it does not work